# Get ValueType with XPathNavigator

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I try to get the value type of an `XElement` by using the `XPathNavigator`, but the ValueType always returns as type `String`.
I have expected that the navigator returns the ValueType as specified in the XSD document.

Loading the xml and xsd:

```
XmlReaderSettings aSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
aSettings.Schemas.Add(myXmlSchemaSet);
aSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

XmlReader aReader = XmlReader.Create(PathToXml, aSettings);
XDocument aDocument = XDocument.Load(aReader);
aDocument.Validate(aSchemaSet, null, true);
```

Get value type:

```
XPathNavigator aNavigator = aDocument.CreateNavigator();
Type aElementType = aNavigator.SelectSingleNode(myXPath).ValueType;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML to LINQ doesn't support this feature because XNodeNavigator does not implement IXmlSchemaInfo and does not override XPathNavigator.SchemaInfo.

You can use System.Xml which supports that.